# Is there anyway to get the DataStage jobs path from command line?

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

I have gone through all the dsjob commands and output of them to see if there is any command which returns the DataStage jobs path. But there is no luck for me.

If the DataStage job is in /Jobs/Oracle/Export, I would like to get the path name by using any command. Please let me know if there is any way to get it.

Answer (score 0):

`cpdctl dsjob jobinfo` command will list job information, so with this you will be able to fetch job path.